# NHibernate - flush before/after select?

Tags: nhibernate, flush

Currently I am working on a project, that was programmed by someone else and it is known that the NHibernate part might not be well implemented. I was asked to improve that during my internship, but I am also very new to NHibernate.
I came across some code parts where there was a Flush after a select, in my opinion that is completely useless, am I right (question 1)?
I read almost the complete NHibernate Documentation but I am not sure I understand everything.

Should I flush before a select (question 2)? My thoughts are that the data would be up to date when I select after a flush.

(Currently the program doesn't use any transactions at all - I see a lot of room for improvement there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NH Official [documents](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing) say:

> **9.7.1. Flushing the Session**
>
> If you happen to be using the ITransaction API, you don't need to
>   worry about this step. It will be performed implicitly when the
>   transaction is committed. Otherwise you should call ISession.Flush()
>   to ensure that all changes are synchronized with the database.

You [should always use transactions](http://ayende.com/blog/3775/nh-prof-alerts-use-of-implicit-transactions-is-discouraged), even for a read.

If you're not using transaction you should use Flush after a write.
It doesn't really make sens to Flush after a read.
Have a look a these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/780918/219406) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43567/219406) where everything is explained very well.