# NHibernate requires a transaction in order for updates to succeed

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Using NHibernate, in my NUnit tests I might make a call such as `session.Delete(_user)` where `_user` is a persistent object.

My problem seems to be that unless I have this and any other updates included within a transaction, it never succeeds.

So,

```
CurrentSessionContext.Bind(GetHibernateSessionFactory().OpenSession());
ITransaction trans=session.BeginTransaction()
session.Delete(_user);
trans.Commit();
CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(GetHibernateSessionFactory())
```

works.

but,

```
CurrentSessionContext.Bind(GetHibernateSessionFactory().OpenSession());
session.Delete(_user);
CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(GetHibernateSessionFactory())
```

doesn't, yet there are no exceptions or problems being reported.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NHibernate will only send updates / inserts / deletes to the database, when the session is being flushed.

You can do that explicitly by calling Flush(), but you should also look at the configuration: you can specify the default flushing behaviour there as well.

Interesting reads:

[NHibernate ISession Flush: Where and when to use it, and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320/nhibernate-isession-flush-where-and-when-to-use-it-and-why)
[NHibernate Flush-- How it works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780755/nhibernate-flush-how-it-works)

Comment: Sorted! The link is very useful. In summary, always use a transaction.