# NHibernate Custom Collections hack works outside of a transaction, but not inside

Tags: nhibernate, collections

Following the technique described [here](http://colinjack.blogspot.com/2008/09/nhibernate-mapping-custom-collections.html), I was able to populate a domain object that uses custom collections for its children.  The relevant property mapping looks like this:

```
    <component name="Contacts" class="My.CustomList`1[[Domain.Object, DomainAssembly]], MyAssembly">
        <set name="InnerList">
            <key column="PARENT_ID" />
            <one-to-many class="Contact" />
        </set>
    </component>
```

My custom collection class exposes the InnerList property as an `ICollection` like so:

```
    protected System.Collections.ICollection InnerList
    {
        get
        {
            return this;
        }
        set
        {
            Clear();
            foreach (DomainObject o in value)
            {
                Add(o);
            }
        }
    }
```

This worked like a charm to load data from the database and not have to abandon my rather useful custom collection class.

Then I moved on to try implement saving, and following the advice [given in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320/nhibernate-isession-flush-where-and-when-to-use-it-and-why), decided to wrap every call to NHibernate in a transaction.

Now when I commit following my load, NHibernate throws an `InvalidCastException`: "Unable to cast object of type 'My.CustomList`1[Domain.Object, DomainAssembly]' to type 'Iesi.Collections.ISet'."

Is there a way to make this work the way I expect it to?

EDIT:

Following the lead provided by Raphael, I tried switching to `ICollection<T>` which gives me a different `InvalidCastException` when I commit the transaction: Unable to cast object of type 'My.CustomList`1[Domain.Object]' to type 'NHibernate.Collection.IPersistentCollection'.

Comment: Your InnerList (and hence - your CustomCollection) when created - does that implement ISet from Iesi.Collections? If it doesn't - that's where your problem is at.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having a dependency on Iesi.Collections in my domain, which is why I am using the "hack" in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Change the property to be of type

```
IList<T>
```

Comment: Using IList<T> and a set mapping causes the initial query to fail when it tries to cast NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericSet`1[MyDomain.Contact] to System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[MyDomain.Contact].  PersistentGenericSet supports ICollection and ICollection<T> but not IList<T>.