# NHibernate: get the incremented value of version property after updating the entity

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Let's assume, there is an entity:

```
class Book
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public int Version { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

The appropriate Fluent NHibernate-mapping:

```
class BookMapping : ClassMap<Book>
{
    public BookMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
        Version(x => x.Version);
        Map(x => x.Author);
        Map(x => x.Title);
    }
}
```

I would like to get the incremented value of the `Version` property after `IStatelessSession.Update()` method call for the `Book` instance to perform the related update of another entity (see the comment):

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession())
{
    using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        session.Update(book);

        // Is it safe to use the value of the book.Version property here?
        //
        // Just for example:
        // bookReference.ID = book.ID;
        // bookReference.Version = book.Version; // I would like to have the latest (incremented) version here.
        // session.Insert(bookReference);

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Currently the debugging shows it works as desired.
But I have not found the documentation which states that such behavior, i.e. increasing the version value after `IStatelessSession.Update()` method call, **is guaranteed** by NHibernate.

1. Could you please provide the reference to the appropriate official documentation? Is there such guarantee?
2. Which methods can cause the increment of the `Version` value before the `ITransaction.Commit()` method is called?

Comment: The related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307530/how-should-nhibernate-update-properties-mapped-as-version.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior described above is not random.

More than `doc` *(not sure about it)* could be to observe the code. The update of any entity is at the end delegated to the:

#### [EntityUpdateAction.cs](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Action/EntityUpdateAction.cs#L44)

Its method **`Execute()`** is below (just essential parts)

```
public override void Execute()
{
    ... // some importan stuff

    // here the UPDATE is executed
    if (!veto)
    {
        persister.Update(id, state, dirtyFields, hasDirtyCollection, 
                         previousState, previousVersion, instance, null, session);
    }

    EntityEntry entry = Session.PersistenceContext.GetEntry(instance);
    if (entry == null)
    {
        throw new AssertionFailure("Possible nonthreadsafe access to session");
    }

    // HERE we can see that NHibernate is going for GENERATED properties
    // imeditally 
    if (entry.Status == Status.Loaded || persister.IsVersionPropertyGenerated)
    {
        // get the updated snapshot of the entity state by cloning current state;
        // it is safe to copy in place, since by this time no-one else (should have)
        // has a reference  to the array
        TypeHelper.DeepCopy(state, persister.PropertyTypes,
                            persister.PropertyCheckability, state, Session);
        if (persister.HasUpdateGeneratedProperties)
        {
            // this entity defines property generation, so process those generated
            // values...
            persister.ProcessUpdateGeneratedProperties(id, instance, state, Session);
```

And this is the `IPersister` method **`ProcessUpdateGeneratedProperties()`** description:

```
/// <summary>
/// Perform a select to retrieve the values of any generated properties
/// back from the database, injecting these generated values into the
/// given entity as well as writing this state to the persistence context.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Note, that because we update the persistence context here, callers
/// need to take care that they have already written the initial snapshot
/// to the persistence context before calling this method. 
/// </remarks>
/// <param name="id">The entity's id value.</param>
/// <param name="entity">The entity for which to get the state.</param>
/// <param name="state">The entity state (at the time of Save).</param>
/// <param name="session">The session.</param>
void ProcessUpdateGeneratedProperties(object id, object entity, 
         object[] state, ISessionImplementor session);
```

So, for sure, the behavior you experience is not random. It is driven by fact, that there are generated properties - generated by DB. NHibernate does always reload these, after every update...

To touch the second part, the only place where this is called is: **`session.Flush()`**. That could be part of the commit, but is in fact dependent on SessionFlush Mode *(which could be even **`Never`** and we have to / can do it manually)*. Anyhow, once real DB UPDATE is triggered, it goes in the above bundle, and we can be sure, that DB generated properties are up to date