# Objects not getting saved properly in Database

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

```
[Test]
public void Artist_gets_stored_properly()
{
    using (ISession session = NHHelper.GetSession())
    {
        Artist artist = new Artist() { Name = "Somathilaka Jayamaha" };

        artist.Songs = new List<Song>()
        {
            new Song(){Artist = artist, Name = "Manamaala girawu"},
            new Song(){Artist = artist, Name = "Sende andura"},
            new Song(){Artist = artist, Name = "Sunilwan nuwan"}
        };

        foreach (var s in artist.Songs)
        {
            session.Save(s);
        }
        session.Save(artist);
    }

    using (ISession session = NHHelper.GetSession())
    {
        Artist artist = session.Query<Artist>().Single(x => x.Name == "Somathilaka Jayamaha");
        Assert.AreEqual(3, artist.Songs.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("Sende andura", artist.Songs[1].Name);
    }
}

public class Artist
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Song> Songs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Song
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string WebPath { get; set; }
        public virtual string FilePath { get; set; }
        public virtual bool Downloaded { get; set; }
        public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }

        void Download(IDownloader downloader)
        {
        }
    }
```

I have the above test case and it fails at this line : `Assert.AreEqual(3, artist.Songs.Count);`. The songs do not get saved it seems. I use automapping and have `Cascade.All()` for the collection fields in mapping overrides and have lazyloading off. I can't understand why this test fails. As you can see, I manually saved the 3 songs as well though as I understand it, I don't need to do that when I have `Cascade.All()` for `Artist.Songs` field. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

MS SQLServer 2005, .NET 3.5, FluentNHibernate 1.2.0.712

Comment: What is your flush mode set to? `FlushMode.?`

Comment: Also how are you dealing with transactions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using a transaction, and you are never flushing your session.

The only reason you are getting the *inserts* is because you are using an `identity` generator, which inserts when you call `Save` (this is a limitation, not a feature).

The correct way to to this:

```
using (ISession session = NHHelper.GetSession())
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    Artist artist = new Artist { Name = "Somathilaka Jayamaha" };

    artist.Songs = new List<Song>()
    {
        new Song{Artist = artist, Name = "Manamaala girawu"},
        new Song{Artist = artist, Name = "Sende andura"},
        new Song{Artist = artist, Name = "Sunilwan nuwan"}
    };

    session.Save(artist);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Indeed; some interesting reads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320/nhibernate-isession-flush-where-and-when-to-use-it-and-why