# Nhibernate doesn't update object id

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have issue with NHibernate it some times it doesn't update ID property

User Map Class

```
public class SfGuardUserMap : ClassMap<User> {

    public SfGuardUserMap() {
        Table("sf_guard_user");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("id");
        Map(x => x.FirstName).Column("first_name");
        Map(x => x.LastName).Column("last_name");
        Map(x => x.EmailAddress).Column("email_address").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Sex).Column("sex").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Lang).Column("lang");
        Map(x => x.City).Column("city");
```

Executable code

```
var user = new User
                       {
                           FirstName = usr.FirstName,
                           EmailAddress = usr.Email,
                           LastName = usr.LastName,
                           Sex = usr.Sex,
                           Birthdate = usr.Birthday,
                           IsActive = User.IS_ACTIVE_ACTIVE
                       };
        var t = (int)session.Save(user);
        session.Flush();
```

I had issues and user.Id was always 0. But when I restarted iis my issue gone.

I have a bit the same issue with other class. Is this here any property insert to database when I call `Save`?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure what is the problem given your description, but I believe that I can give some pointers based on the code you've posted:

1. you're using Identity ID generator; that means that you allow your database to generate the ids of entities as you insert them. This approach is [not recommended](http://ayende.com/blog/3915/nhibernate-avoid-identity-generator-when-possible). I would suggest using HiLo as your id generator. If you stick with identity, however, you should make sure that your db is configured accordingly.
2. it's recommended to [always use transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43567/537913) instead of explicitly calling `Flush`.

if these suggestion don't help you, I suggest you detail some more on your issue- what are you seeing (are the objects saved in the db? is the id returned always 0?)

Comment: Probably you answered my problem so i will try and reply if it help me.