# Nhibernate QueryOver don't get latest database changes

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria, queryover

I am trying get a record updated from database with `QueryOver`.
My code initially creates an entity and saves in database, then the same record is updated on database externally( from other program, manually or the same program running in other machine), and when I call `queryOver` filtering by the field changed, the query gets the record but *without* latest changes.

This is my code:

```
//create the entity and save in database
MyEntity myEntity = CreateDummyEntity();
myEntity.Name = "new_name";

MyService.SaveEntity(myEntity);

// now the entity is updated externally changing the name property with the 
// "modified_name" value (for example manually in TOAD, SQL Server,etc..)

//get the entity with QueryOver
var result = NhibernateHelper.Session
                 .QueryOver<MyEntity>()
                 .Where(param => param.Name == "modified_name")
                 .List<T>();
```

The previous statement gets a collection with only one record(good), **BUT** with the name property established **with the old value** instead of "modified_name".

How I can fix this behaviour? First Level cache is disturbing me? The same problem occurs with

```
CreateCriteria<T>();
```

The session in my NhibernateHelper is not being closed in any moment due application framework requirements, only are created transactions for each commit associated to a session.Save().
If I open a new session to execute the query evidently I get the latest changes from database, but this approach is not allowed by design requirement.

Also I have checked in the NHibernate SQL output that a select with a WHERE clause is being executed (therefore Nhibernate hits the database) but don´t updates the  returned object!!!!

### UPDATE

Here's the code in SaveEntity after to call session.Save: A call to Commit method is done

```
public virtual void Commit() 
{ 
  try 
  { 
    this.session.Flush(); 
    this.transaction.Commit();
  } 
  catch 
  { 
    this.transaction.Rollback(); 
    throw; 
  } 
  finally 
  { 
    this.transaction = this.session.BeginTransaction();
  } 
}
```

The SQL generated by NHibernate for SaveEntity:

```
NHibernate: INSERT INTO MYCOMPANY.MYENTITY (NAME) VALUES (:p0);:p0 = 'new_name'.
```

The SQL generated by NHibernate for QueryOver:

```
NHibernate: SELECT this_.NAME as NAME26_0_ 
            FROM MYCOMPANY.MYENTITY this_ 
            WHERE this_.NAME = :p0;:p0 = 'modified_name' [Type: String (0)].
```

Queries has been modified due to company confidential policies.

Help very appreciated.

Comment: this may sound silly, but once in a project we shifted the database from SQLServer to Oracle and we were connecting to it through an oracle PL/SQL developer. I would make changes to it manually through the oracle client and then run my application and the old values were being returned, not the updated ones. Turns out I had to manually `COMMIT` the database inserts/updates.

Comment: @Carlos. Just to confirm if you check the DB `MyEntity.Name` is populated with 'modified_name' before you perform the `QueryOver`? Also the line `this.session.Flush();` is unnecessary as the call to `Commit()` will perform the flushing for you.

Comment: @penfold: of course, the name is succesfully populated in the database before to execute the `queryOver()`, because I set a breakPoint after to execute the query and I check that the database is updated. Thank you for additional information about `session.FLush().`

Comment: @mridula, I dont understand you when you says **Turns out I had to manually COMMIT the database inserts/updates.**. What did you do to get the latest changes?

Comment: well, after making changes to the records using the oracle client, I had to run the `commit` command for the changes to take effect in the database. I was used to working with SQLServer, which does not need this manual `commit`. So then when I ran my application, the changes were not visible because I hadn't `commit`ed them.

Comment: ok, you had other different problem (autocommit disabled).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After search and search and think and think.... I´ve found the solution.

The fix: It consist in open a new session, call `QueryOver<T>()` in this session and the data is succesfully refreshed. If you get child collections not initialized you can call `HibernateUtil.Initialize(entity)` or sets `lazy="false"` in your mappings. Take special care about `lazy="false"` in large collections, because you can get a poor performance. To fix this problem(performance problem loading large collections), set `lazy="true"` in your collection mappings and call the mentioned method `HibernateUtil.Initialize(entity)` of the affected collection to get child records from database; for example, you can get all records from a table, and if you need access to all child records of a specific entity, call `HibernateUtil.Initialize(collection)` only for the interested objects.

Note: as @martin ernst says, the update problem can be a bug in hibernate and my solution is only a temporal fix, and must be solved in hibernate.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, you have several options :

- have your Session as a `IStatelessSession`, by calling `sessionFactory.OpenStatelesSession()` instead of `sessionFactory.OpenSession()`
- perform `Session.Evict(myEntity)` after persisting an entity in DB
- perform `Session.Clear()` before your `QueryOver`
- set the `CacheMode` of your Session to `Ignore, Put or Refresh` before your `QueryOver` (never tested that)

I guess the choice will depend on the usage you have of your long running sessions ( which, IMHO, seem to bring more problems than solutions )

Comment: Thank you very much @jbl, but I already have tried all options indicated by you, and nothing is valid in my context due to design requirements (only one session for the entire application lifecycle)

Comment: @Carlos : these should do the trick for a first level cache problem. Does your application use some custom behaviors for  lazy-loading, interceptors, second level cache ? The issue might be there.

Comment: No, second level cache is not beind referenced, and the unique specific case with relevant changes is in the collection mappings as there(a 1:N relationship): `<bag name="MyChild" inverse="true" cascade="all">
      <key>
        <column name="MYCOLUMN" not-null="true" />
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="MyChild" />
    </bag>`

Comment: @Carlos : from the code you provide, it seems like you are trying to implement string collections. It also seems you are altering the key column. You should add your mappings to your question.

Comment: No, there are not string collections, are custom objects collections. Its a single object with some properties, no more relevant information required on this context. Thank you very much for your interest.

Comment: Another Thing, I was having problem with a property that is mapped as a one-to-one rellation, After I save an entity, this property wasn´t being refreshed . Example: Property One to One: User.Colaborator.Manager   if I add a Manager, and try to get all User, the Manager of User.Colaborator will not have a Manager, but doing a Session.Clear worked for me!

Comment: I got Another Problem with Session.Clear, i got a LazyInitializeException. Because the session has finished when I did the session.Clear

Answer (score 2):

Calling `session.Save(myEntity)` **does not cause the changes to be persisted to the DB immediately***. These changes are persisted when `session.Flush()` is called either by the framework itself or by yourself. More information about flushing and when it is invoked can be found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320/nhibernate-isession-flush-where-and-when-to-use-it-and-why) question and the [nhibernate documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320/nhibernate-isession-flush-where-and-when-to-use-it-and-why) about flushing.

Also **performing a query will not cause the first level cache to be hit**. This is because the first level cache only works with `Get` and `Load`, i.e. `session.Get<MyEntity>(1)` would hit the first level cache if `MyEntity` with an `id` of 1 had already been previously loaded, whereas `session.QueryOver<MyEntity>().Where(x => x.id == 1)` would not.

Further information about NHibernate's caching functionality can be found in [this](http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/28/first-and-second-level-caching-in-nhibernate) post by Ayende Rahien.

In summary you have two options:

1. Use a transaction within the `SaveEntity` method, i.e.

   ```
   using (var transaction = Helper.Session.BeginTransaction())
   {
     Helper.Session.Save(myEntity);
     transaction.Commit();
   }
   ```
2. Call `session.Flush()` within the `SaveEntity` method, i.e.

   ```
     Helper.Session.Save(myEntity);
     Helper.Session.Flush();
   ```

The first option is the best in pretty much **all** scenarios.

*The only exception I know to this rule is when using `Identity` as the id generator type.

Comment: Thank you @penfold, I forget indicate you that my service called SaveEntity also perform all steps that you indicates ( I perform flush and commit) therefore the save process always has gone OK. I continue with the problem, because your approach is being performed in my code anyway.

Comment: @Carlos. Would it be possible for you to update the question to include your implementation of `SaveEntity`, and the SQL generated by NHibernate for both the 'SaveEntity' and subsequent 'QueryOver'.

Comment: Of course @penfold, here the code in SaveEntity after to call session.Save: A call to Commit method is done --> `
        public virtual void Commit()
        {
            try
            {
                this.session.Flush();
                this.transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch
            {
                this.transaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                this.transaction = this.session.BeginTransaction();
            }
        }`

Comment: -The SQL generated by NHibernate for SaveEntity: NHibernate: INSERT INTO MYCOMPANY.MYENTITY (NAME) VALUES (:p0);:p0 = 'new_name'. -The SQL generated by NHibernate for QueryOver: NHibernate: SELECT this_.NAME as NAME26_0_ FROM MYCOMPANY.MYENTITY this_ WHERE this_.NAME = :p0;:p0 = 'modified_name' [Type: String (0)].  Queries has been modified due to company confidential policies.

Comment: I insist in say that the save process is ok, the wrong result on hibernate is the problem. I don´t understand why hibernare perform a select query but then no fill the object returned and gets from cache!

Answer (score 1):

try changing your last query to:

```
 var result = NhibernateHelper.Session
             .QueryOver<MyEntity>()
             .CacheMode(CacheMode.Refresh)
             .Where(param => param.Name == "modified_name")
```

if that still doesn't work, try add this after the query:

```
NhibernateHelper.Session.Refresh(result);
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I had tried with your second approach **NhibernateHelper.Session.Refresh(result);** previously successfully, but I want avoid the refresh method. Your first approach still not working. Thank you very much other time.

Comment: if the second approach works, then it looks like a bug in NHibernate - you could try call Session.Clear() before the query

Comment: Yeah, **Session.Clear()** works but all objects are Evict, and I dont want this.

Comment: You can log a bug report for NHibernate, and/or fix it yourself since it's open source...

Answer (score 0):

People here do not want to call `Session.Clear()` since it is too strong.

On the other hand, `Session.Evict()` may seem un-applicable when the objects are not known beforehand.

Actually it is still usable. 

You need to first retrieve the cached objects using the query, then call `Evict()` on them. And then again retrieve fresh objects calling the same query again.

This approach is slightly inefficient in case the object was not cached to begin with - since then there would be actually two "fresh" queries - but there seems to be not much to do about that shortcoming...

By the way, `Evict()` accepts null argument too without exceptions - this is useful in case the queried object is actually not present in the DB.

```
var cachedObjects = NhibernateHelper.Session
             .QueryOver<MyEntity>()
             .Where(param => param.Name == "modified_name")
             .List<T>();

foreach (var obj in cachedObjects) 
    NhibernateHelper.Session.Evict(obj);

var freshObjects = NhibernateHelper.Session
             .QueryOver<MyEntity>()
             .Where(param => param.Name == "modified_name")
             .List<T>()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting something very similar, and have tried debugging NHibernate.
In my scenario, the session creates an object with a couple children in a related collection (cascade:all), and then calls `ISession.Flush()`.
The records are written into the DB, and the session needs to continue without closing. Meanwhile, another two child records are written into the DB and committed. 
Once the original session then attempts to re-load the graph using `QueryOver` with `JoinAlias`, the SQL statement generated looks perfectly fine, and the rows are being returned correctly, however the collection that should receive these new children is found to have already been initialized within the session (as it should be), and based on that NH decides for some reason to completely ignore the respective rows. 
I think NH makes an invalid assumption here that if the collection is already marked "Initialized" it does not need to be re-loaded from the query.
It would be great if someone more familiar with NHibernate internals could chime in on this.

Comment: Ok, after a bit more digging, this appears to be the default behavior in NH.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nhusers/UAvGM0Tql1w